# Cannot compile Windows app with C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin Update 2

Tags: c++builder

I installed RAD Studio 10.1 Update 2 using the web installer. It uninstalled the previous 10.1 Update 1 and performed everything without error messages.

The new version is able to build C++ projects for Android, iOS, and Mac OSX. But when I try to compile projects for Win32, both VCL and FMX, I get this unexpected error:

```
[bcc32 Error] windows.h(1): E2209 Unable to open include file 'winapifamily.h'
  Full parser context
    Project1.cpp(3): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include\windows\vcl\vcl.h
    vcl.h(10): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include\windows\vcl\basepch0.h
    basepch0.h(62): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include\windows\rtl\System.hpp
    System.hpp(19): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include\windows\rtl\sysmac.h
    sysmac.h(141): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include\windows\sdk\windows.h
```

Answer (score 2):

From the following article on EDN:

[Issues with winapifamily.h and other header files after installing C++Builder 10](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/articles-support/171-rad-studio/16436-issues-with-winapifamily-h-and-other-header-files-after-installing-c-builder-10)

> There is a known issue where occasionally, after the C++Builder and RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin Update 2 installer has run, eight header files may be missing from C++Builder’s include\windows\sdk folder.
>
> The bug manifests as trying to build a Windows C++ application, and getting a compiler error at the top of windows.h stating that winapifamily.h was not found.
>
> These eight headers are available in a zip file for download.
>
> Installation
>
> It is not necessary to close RAD Studio or C++Builder.
>
> [Download the zip file](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30649).  Right-click on it and choose Extract All, and ensure the checkbox ‘Show extracted files when complete’ is checked. Click Extract.
>
> Once the extraction is complete and the folder where the files were extracted to is opened, select all eight header files, right-click on them, and select Copy.
>
> Open another Explorer window and navigate to:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\include\windows\sdk
>
> Right-click in an empty space in the folder, and click Paste. You will be prompted for administrative permissions in order to paste into this folder. Ensure ‘Do this for all current items’ is checked, and click Continue.
>
> Once complete, return to C++Builder and you should be able to successfully compile.

Comment: Perfect!
Thank you Remy!